# Getting 'CSS Selector' is not supported for this session issue with appium

Tags: java, android, automation, appium

I got an 'CSS Selector' error while using `driver.findElementById("identifier")` in automation scripts with **appium using Java1.8** with Maven dependency.

Appium terminal version: v1.15.1

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The issue got resolved when i update my Maven dependency with latest appium version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to know why this issue happened.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely a selenium-java dependency mix. Please remove selenium java from maven if it is part of the dependency. Clear the IDE cache and do a clean build.